# How to design the array structure for Multiple cells in UITableview?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

This is my first `ViewController` ,when I will click on plus(+) button, it will move to the `SecondViewController`

[image]

This is my `SecondViewController`, after giving the required field when I will click on save button it should add one more row in  my `tableview` respective cell(executive,seniormanagement,staff). But it's not adding the row in respective cells.

[image]

This my code what i have tired

### FirstViewController

```
  class TableViewHeader: UIViewController ,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource,EmployeeProtocol{

 @IBOutlet weak var tableviewHeader: UITableView!


 var employee = [ EmployeeStatus(status:"Executive",Name:["Smith","Dev","Aryan"], Date:["Nov  14 1889","Dec  01  1980","Sep  18  1997"]),

                 EmployeeStatus(status:"SeniorManagement",Name:["Sourav","Smarak"], Date:[" April  10  1879"," Dec  11  1990"]),

                 EmployeeStatus(status:"Staff",Name:["Smith","Dev","Aryan","Suman"], Date:["Feb  14 1234"," Jan  01  1480","Sep  23  1994","July  10  1991"])]

@IBAction func plusButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "showSegue", sender:self)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showSegue" {
        let createSegue = segue.destination as!  CreateEmployeeViewController

        createSegue.myEmpProtocol = self
    }
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return employee.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 50
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return employee[section].Name.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 70
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let Label = UILabel()
    Label.text = employee[section].status
    Label.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
    return Label
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableviewHeader.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableHeaderCell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewHeadercell
    cell.NameLabel.text = employee[indexPath.section].Name[indexPath.row]
    cell.DateLabel.text = employee[indexPath.section].Date[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}

func addData(status:String, Name:[String], Date:[String]) {
    employee.append(EmployeeStatus(status:status, Name:Name, Date: Date))
    tableviewHeader.reloadData()
}
}
```

### SeconViewController

```
    protocol EmployeeProtocol {
        func addData(status:String, Name:[String], Date:[String])
       }

   class CreateEmployeeViewController: UIViewController {

    var myEmpProtocol:EmployeeProtocol?


@IBOutlet weak var nameTextField: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var birthdayTextField: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var StatusSegment: UISegmentedControl!


var name  = [String]()
var DOB = [String]()
var status:String = ""

@IBAction func saveButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    self.name = [nameTextField.text!]
    self.DOB = [birthdayTextField.text!]
    if StatusSegment.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
        self.status = "Executive"
    } else if StatusSegment.selectedSegmentIndex == 1{
        self.status = "SeniorManagement"
    }  else if StatusSegment.selectedSegmentIndex == 2 {
        self.status = "Staff"
    }
    myEmpProtocol?.addData(status:status, Name:name, Date:DOB)

}

@IBAction func CancelButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

}
```

### MyClass

```
 import Foundation
  struct EmployeeStatus {
   var status:String
   var Name:[String]
   var Date:[String]
 init(status:String, Name:[String], Date:[String]){
    self.status = status
    self.Name = Name
    self.Date = Date
   }
```

Comment: In your `secondViewController` where are you calling your custom delegate method?

Comment: show your second page code

Comment: Show your SecondViewController code

Comment: Use lowerCamelCase for variables and arguments https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/

Comment: @AbecedarioPoint yes i have edited my code now you can  check

Comment: Are you presenting or Pushing your SecondViewController? and you will have to `pop` or `dismiss` it after saving.

Comment: @Laxmipriya Try debugging again and make your "tableviewHeader" in addData in FirstViewController is not nil.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current code is adding the new `EmployeeStatus` to `employee` array, not the item's `EmployeeStatus.Name` array and `EmployeeStatus.Date` array.

Please try this code.

```
func addData(status:String, Name:[String], Date:[String]) {
    var arr = [EmployeeStatus]()
    employee.forEach { ele in
        if ele.status == status {
            var e = ele
            e.Name.append(Name[0])
            e.Date.append(Date[0])
            arr.append(e)
        } else {
            arr.append(ele)
        }
    }
    employee = arr
    tableviewHeader.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: i think ,i am reloading tableview in a wrong place ,not sure

Comment: @Laxmipriya Put a breakpoint at `addData` method to check if it has been called and the new item has been added into `employee`.

Comment: yes addData() is calling fine and i am getting value

Comment: @Laxmipriya You can avoid it by structuring your data differently. A data structure is to help make operations easy, and your shown structure makes adding employees to it complicated.

Comment: @NF Lee Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

In this way, you can pass value from one view controller to another tab:

1. First of all open main.storyboard
2. Select the First view controller and drag and drop UItextField and UIButton on the field.

Answer (score 0):

Your data looks interesting. It might work better with

```
enum Level: Int {
    case executive = 0, seniorManagement, staff
    var stringValue: { return (String:description: self).capitalizingFirstLetter }
}
struct Employee {
    let name: String
    let date: String
}

var employees: [Level: [Employee]] = [
    .executive: [Employee(name: "Smith", date: "Nov  14 1889"],
    .seniorManagement: [],
    .staff: []]
```

Then you can add employees with:

```
guard let level = Level(rawValue: status) else {
    throw Errors.levelDoesNotExist(status)
}
employees[.level] = newEmployee
```

Reloading the tableView works as you do already. Just the data is in a format where its weird to add to.

And best dismiss the second viewController once its finished after the `addData` delegate call so its going back to the first to show the updated data.

Comment: I did already, look at what I wrote. Have you tried integrating that?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set your view controller as a table view delegate and datasource.

Add to the end of the `viewDidLoad` at `TableViewHeader` class:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableviewHeader.delegate = self
    tableviewHeader.dataSource = self
}
```